# Response code is 404 in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, postman

```
package controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("users") //localhost:8080/users
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getUser()
    {
        return "get the user";
    }
    @PostMapping
    public String creteUser()
    {
        return "create user";
    }
    @PutMapping
    public String updateUser()
    {
        return "update user";
    }
    @DeleteMapping
    public  String deleteUser()
    {
        return "delete user";
    }

}
```

This is the code, I don't what's wrong with it. Application is running fine still getting no response. I have added all required dependencies.

Comment: Solved, It was due to package folder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Post your answer to help new people in Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Hi, please consider reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the mapping again, there might be an incorrect URI while making the request.

Create UserNotFoundException class. It is a checked exception. Spring Boot auto-configures some default exception handling.

It would be good if we define a standard exception structure that is followed by across all the RESTful Services.